Using the `l3` layer to define headings
Further to my previous question regarding a package I am developing and in which I failed miserably to communicate some of the concepts clearly, here is what I am trying to achieve. The package is to enable authors to use different style headings easily and to change a list of parameters using key-value lists. Template designers can define new templates or in many cases just fork an existing one and do some changes. In the package, all the pre-canned templates are saved, as |.sty|, so authors can load what the need. The templates have memorable names,
in the code below I show two examples, one named andrea and another named athena.
In the previous question David Carlisle suggested and explained the reasons to have clear separation between the |l3| layer commands and using \NewDocumentCommand etc. as this generalizes the package better. I have partially adopted his suggestion which is very good as one can use this higher level command to produce html, xhtml, interface with Lua etc. He also made another good suggestion to have another look at the tagpdf project and code, and to regard the hyperref code as legacy. In this respect also I added a key like |chapter.role = H| so it can be picked up and the necessary tag be added. Ulrike suggested to add  |\MakeLinkTarget| to resolve an issue with links.
I try to automate the generation of code using a concept I call element(s) The definition is in the comments in the code provided below.
I use swedish as the main babel language just for testing that babel strings are handled correctly.
Question:
Babel's  \AddBabelHook{noshort}{afterextras}{\languageshorthands{none}} does not disable all shorthands. Try it with turkish and you will see that it interferes with the = in key val defs. Should I do an Oberdiek? here and ensure that the package receives all catcodes properly? Is there an easy way with l3 cctab?
As always your general review of the code is appreciated. Please note the key-lists are incomplete as well as some of the code, as I wanted to reduce the length of the code I provide. I define them using pgf keys, as IMHO mainly due to the ease I can define handlers and styles.

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\AddBabelHook{noshort}{afterextras}{\languageshorthands{none}}
%
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
% internal code
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% Scratch variables
\tl_new:N \yl_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \yl_tmpb_tl
\newcounter{my} % used for targets replaces phantom section
\def\theHmy{\themy}
% Primary elements are elements such as chapter. They
% can appear in tocs and contents lists. Secondary elements are items such as labels numbers and titles in headings.
% In key value lists. Each one of them can have attributes aka properties. 
% There is an implied hierarchy denoted by the level as in traditional LaTeX sectioning commands. For tagged pdfs
% they can interface through the key lists.
% I represent them with keys using a dot separator rather than just space dashes or none. By convention all keys
% and values are lower case with some exceptions such as Roman, roman, AlphAlph etc. It is convenient to think of them as
% objects as they establish clear boundaries without interfering with each other. 
%
% chapter.name            = chapter,
% chapter.level           = 1,           
% chapter.format          = andrea,      <-- named formatter
% chapter.title.font.size = Huge,        <-- large, LARGE but also 10pt/12pt, 
% chapter.title.font.series = bfseries   <-- but also bold,      
% chapter.label.case      = upper,       <-- but also upper, lower, ucfirst,
% chapter.numbering       = arabic,    
% chapter.pagestyle      = plain,
% chapter.Role or tag     = H,           <-- not sure need to study the docs a bit more carefully. 
%                                            is only a provision for now.   
%
% All key lists and functions are generated by factory commands (aka constructors) to make the system flexible and 
% extensible.  
%
\def\pkgfamilyname{phd}
\cs_if_exist:NTF \cxset{} {    
        \pgfkeys{/\pkgfamilyname/.is~family} 
 
    \newcommand\cxset{\pgfqkeys{/\pkgfamilyname}} 

    \def\cxkeydef#1#2{%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/\pkgfamilyname/#1}{#2}%
    }
    \def\cxvalueof#1{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/\pkgfamilyname/#1}%
    }
}
\cxset{chapter.format/.code=\def\mychapterformat{\csname#1\endcsname},
       chapter.color/.code = \def\mychaptercolor,
       chapter.level/.code= \def\mychapterlevel,
       chapter.short/.store~in =\savedshorttitle,
       chapter.thispagestyle/.code=\def\chapterpagestyle{\thispagestyle{#1}},
       }
\cxset{chapter.format=ulrike,chapter.short=,
       chapter.thispagestyle={plain}
 }

% Elements are specified in a clist. These are the internal defaults, later we can provide user commands to set
% them differently.
\clist_new:N  \yl__document_sectioning_clist  
\clist_set:Nn \yl__document_sectioning_clist{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

% Creates the element commands by iterating through the clists.
\cs_new:Npn \__yl_create_elements:n #1
{
 \clist_map_inline:Nn#1 %eg \yl__document_sectioning_clist or custom
 {   
   \yl__create_element:n {##1}
 }
}  

% creates the element function yl_section_element:nnn this is the internal equivalent to 
% \chapter 
\cs_new:Npn \yl__create_element:n #1
{
  
  % creates functions for primary elements
  \cs_new:cpn {l_yl_#1_element:nnn} ##1 ##2 ##3
   {

        \primary_element_aux:nnn {#1} {##1} {##2} {##3}  %no star  
 
   }

}

% Uses the input and calls the template at the end to render.
\bool_new:N\chapterhasstar_bool

\cs_new:Npn \primary_element_aux:nnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
   % chapter openings
   % save the title
   % id no short title shorttitle=savedtitle
   % put in toc
   % save for nameef
   % chapter mark etc
   % call the template
    \clearpage
    \MakeLinkTarget[sc:mychapter]{my}
    \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{#2}
    \tl_if_empty:NTF\l_tmpa_tl
    {\bool_set_false:N\chapterhasstar_bool}
    { \bool_set_true:N\chapterhasstar_bool }
    {}
    \def\savedtitle{#4}
    \tl_if_blank:VTF{\savedshorttitle}{\let\savedshorttitle\savedtitle}{}
    \def\@currentlabelname{#4}
    \yl__put_in_toc{#1}
    \bool_if:NTF\chapterhasstar_bool{\markboth{}{}}
    {\chaptermark{#4}}
    \use:c{my#1format}
   \@afterindentfalse
   \@afterheading     
}

\def\yl__put_in_toc #1 {
  \stepcounter{my}
              {\typeout{#1\space\csname the #1\endcsname. }}
              \bool_if:NTF\chapterhasstar_bool
              { \MakeLinkTarget[sc:mychapter]{my}
                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{*\space\itshape\savedtitle}
                %\setcounter{section}{0} 
              }
              {
              \legacy_if:nTF{@mainmatter}
                   {%\phantomsection
                     \refstepcounter{chapter}
                     \MakeLinkTarget[sc:mychapter]{my} 
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                     {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\savedtitle}%
                   } 
                   { \MakeLinkTarget[sc:mychapter]{my}    
                     %\phantomsection
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\itshape\savedtitle}%##3
                   }
             }
}



 % Create the elements 
 \__yl_create_elements:n\yl__document_sectioning_clist


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o +m}
{ 
  \def\tempa{
  \IfValueT{#2}{#2}
  \IfValueF{#2}{}
 }
  
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    { \l_yl_chapter_element:nnn {*}{\tempa}{#3} }
    { \l_yl_chapter_element:nnn {}{\tempa}{#3} }
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\andrea{} {%
% \vspace*{10\p@}%
\MakeLinkTarget{my}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        {\bfseries
         \color{teal}
         %\gettext{\doclang}{#2}
         \bool_if:NF\chapterhasstar_bool{\chaptername}}
         \space
         \bool_if:NTF\chapterhasstar_bool
         {*}  % just a marker for testing
        % \thechapter
          {\csname thechapter\endcsname}
         \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries \savedtitle\par\nobreak
        \hrulefill
        \chapterpagestyle 
  }
  \par
  \vskip 40pt
  %\@afterindentfalse
  %\@afterheading
}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\myimage{\rule{5cm}{6cm}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\athena}{}
{\null{ \dimendef\myimageht 0
% Measure the image
 \def\img{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=6cm]{example-image-a}}
 \pgfmathheight{"\img"}
  \pgfmathsetlength\myimageht{\pgfmathresult pt}
     %\pgfmathresult
      \def\gap{4mm}
      \tikzset{lines/.style={line width=4pt,line cap=rect,teal},
           shade1/.style={bottom color=thechaptercolor, top color=black},
           nosep/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt},
           textfont/.style={teal, font={\bfseries\sffamily\huge}}}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,trim left=0]

  \coordinate[yshift=-2.0cm] (a) at (current page.north east);
  \coordinate[yshift=-2.0cm] (b) at (current page.north west);
%% vertical line  
  \coordinate[xshift=2cm,yshift=0.1cm]  (c) at (current page.north west);
%% horizontal line  
   \coordinate[xshift=2cm,yshift=-3cm] (d) at (current page.north west);
    \coordinate[xshift=3cm,yshift=-3cm] (e) at (current page.north west);
  \draw[lines] (a)--(b);
  \draw[lightgray,very thick] (c)--(d);
  \draw[lightgray,very thick] (d)--(e);
  \node[xshift=2pt,yshift=1pt,above right,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt](number) at (d)[textfont] {\thechapter\space};
  \node[xshift=.cm,yshift=0cm,right](number) at (e)[textfont] {\savedtitle};

%% photo
   \node[xshift=-2.5cm,yshift=-.5cm,below left,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,text width=5cm](image) at (a){
   \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=6cm]{example-image-a} %cayley,feynman look good
   }; 
   
%% image frame
\node[xshift={2.5cm+\gap},yshift={173.05261pt/2},outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt](z) at (image){};

\draw[lightgray,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] (z) -- ++(0cm,{-\myimageht-\gap})--++({-5cm-\gap},0);  

%% Subheadings  
 \node[xshift=2cm,yshift=-8cm,orange,right,text width=9cm] at (current page.north west) {\language=-1\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries INTRODUCTORY EXAMPLE\par {{\color{teal}\Large Random Paths and Distortions}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \chapterpagestyle
  %\vskip 7cm
  \@afterindentfalse
    \@afterheading 
}}

\makeatother

%% Test 
\frontmatter
\cxset{chapter.format=andrea}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter
\chapter{The Andrea Template}
 \label{ch:andrea}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\newpage

\cxset{chapter.format=athena}
\chapter{The Athena Template}
\lipsum[1]

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-4]

Click to go to the andrea template\nameref{ch:andrea}

autoref  only captures the number \autoref{ch:andrea}

\end{document}


The book class is an old standard class from the early days of LaTeX 2e. LaTeX document design has progressed a lot since then, and for any serious book project, you’d be better off using memoir (which is based on book) or possibly KOMA (which I sadly have no experience with). Any such keyval document front end layer ought to be built on top of one of these. If you can build a fully featured keyval front end to memoir, I’ll be happy to be your first customer.

But really, what we need is for the LaTeX3 project to provide us with new standard classes named something like l3article, l3book, etc., which are set up using keyval syntax, the same way it is done in ConTeXt. Feel free to lobby the LaTeX3 team to do that. I’ll sign the petition.

@Gaussler I don't think the Team will be willing to do anything about it at the moment, but what we need as soon as feasible is further decoupling of hyperref and the classes. The LaTeX Team must be picking up these same issues and hence we see things like MakeLinkTarget the Property Latex2e module. Currently I am testing agaings koma and std classes to pick up issues. Sadly memoir (is on my list) but is deely wounded as when Peter Wilson developed it, he had to provide packages and overrides all over.

Honestly, what we should do in 2024 is to be be able to do \documentclass{l3book}, and then hyperref, microtype, cleveref, babel, xcolor, etc. are already taken care of. And fontspec and unicode-math for LuaTeX users.

@Gaussler A translation to l3 is not hard, maybe a couple of weeks works, however supporting legacy packages and hyperref it will need a bit of time, especially with all the intricacies  being introduced with the tagging project. What I have at the moment, is a class l4doc that subclasses koma and the standard classes. Pretty much like memoir. I am using it on a number of documents I am working on with my own packages and it works well. One of the documents is >1000 pages so I use it as a feature test:)  At the moment I have packages for frontmatter, colorpalettes, scriptmanagement,  etc.

could you please give your template a different name? I would never use or develop such an overloaded layout with bad spacing and uppercase letters and too many colors.

@UlrikeFischer  No issue I will

@UlrikeFischer  The design (is not mine) the code is. The design is from a book by Pearson Publishers and the designer is Andrea Nix. Th book is a textbook (American style) for linear algebra. I tried to emulate it as close as possible colors and layout.

@yannisl I think the LaTeX3 team might take issues with the name l4doc, seeing that the prefix l3 is reserved for packages and classes related to the LaTeX3 project. I know 4 ≠ 3, but some people might still think that we may one day see a version of LaTeX called LaTeX4.

@Gaussler  True, will rename if and when released in the wild.

@cfr  On using l3  mainly because (the current code of the package) is about 3k loc is mainly of its facilities in mapping clists etc. For example there are user commands to set what sectioning a document has, you can have   chapter and verse only! or add book for the French.  For the demo I did not show these but only demonstrated the chapter. If you touching typography like sectioning commands etc, inevitably there is a mixing of levels, although commands like addcontentsline  can be mapped to l3.

@cfr  templates like the andrea  are expected to be provided by users (if any of the pre-canned) templates are not suitable. These can be programmed as one wishes. As long as the package sees a command \andrea it will render it. So I expect that these will be  mishmash of programming styles like we see in QA on this site.  On the keys, I thought hard about it after watching users for years on this site, users are used to Tikz style key-val lists. As I generate most of these keys also programmatically about 20 prop x 13 sectioning levels, can easily be changed down the line.

@cfr tikz can slow down things for sure, so l3 as well in some cases. I mostly use it in this context if I need absolute positioning. textpos can do it as well and also picture. One can also just use zero width and zero height hbox and vboxes. But then thereare renderings you may want a proper canvas ala a tcolorbox  style heading. If you start looking at some textbooks like genetics, history etc, you will encounter such complexity. My aim is first to get the code written properly using computer science principles, separation of concerns, composabilty etc and then optimize.

I'll delete my comments. there are plenty of questions with weird code mixtures etc. but you asked for code review and posted code which consistently ignores the expl3 naming conventions, ignores xparse's builtin option-processing, uses expl3 to no apparent purpose and implements a complicated tikz method rather than, say, shipout/background which allows absolute positioning out-of-the-box. I mean, it's hard not to mention those things if you're asking explicitly for code review.

\languageshorthands{none} deactivates shorthands, but it doesn't turn them off. There are several mechanisms for the latter: \shorthandoff and the package option shorthands=off.

@JavierBezos Thanks a lot. So when you say deactivates means they cannot be used but still defined and \shorthandsoff undefines them as well?

@JavierBezos Worked like a charm thanks very much

You could use a key=value solution that has no problems with active = signs. For instance expkv or l3keys. Both have a style-equivalent (meta in expkv-def, .meta:n in l3keys). Which handlers do you need that aren't already contained in either of the two?

@Skillmon  Thanks  am using pgfkeys as I have a lot of custom handlers, I am thinking though to take the pain and change them to l3keys.
